# ClassCastException when casting TargetDataLine

Tags: java, audio

I have a program that records the mic for 5 sec and it should play it back after recording it, but an error occurs when casting it to  my line. It occurs when a TargetDataLine is casted to a line.

code:

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
    
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    final SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    sourceLine.open();
    
    info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    final TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    targetLine.open();
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL cannot be cast to class javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine (com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL and javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Answer (score 0):

SDL has a `write` method and TDL has a `read` method. They have `DataLine` in common, but the divergence means you can't convert from one to the other, any more than you can cast an Dog (extends Animal) to a Cat (extends Animal).

[Explanation of Class Cast Error](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting#2-classcastexception)